# Why did Golang discontinue the "netchan" package?

Tags: networking, go

The Golang "netchan" package seems to have been discontinued.

That makes me think that the concept of "networked channels" were not a good practice after all.  (Why wouldn't them just "let it be" otherwise?)

Is this the case?  And if it is, why is that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The old netchan was too intricate.
>
> The problem is to find a way to provide Go channel semantics on top of
>   network hardware and software that, as always, finds a way to defeat
>   all attempts at clean design.
>
> I will continue to ponder.
>
> -rob
>
> [new netchan](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/12bdd37ad9ed4a68/36f607d24e5b4c60)

Comment: Thanks!  I was reading a lot of messages from Rob Pike at Golang-nuts, but didn't find that one.  
So, it's not that channels aren't a good way to communicate and synchronize over the network, only that Rob was not satisfied with that API in particular.

Comment: Rob talks about it here https://youtu.be/sln-gJaURzk?t=2010